# GDB finds source path on local Ubuntu but not in cloud

Tags: linux, debugging, path, gdb, nasm

I have a program that I run on my local Ubuntu 20.04, and I am now running it on a temporary droplet at Digital Ocean running Ubuntu 22.04.  I run the program from the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Compile NASM"
cd /opt/P01_SH/Calc_XYZ
sudo nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf Calc_XYZ.asm
sudo ld -shared Calc_XYZ.o  /opt/P01_SH/_Debug_Wrappers_in_C/Create_Threads_in_C-    Calc_XYZ.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Sprintf_in_C.o  /opt/P01_SH/_Library/POSIX_Shared_Memory.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Virtual_Memory.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Available_Memory.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Memory_Map_File.o -ldl -lrt -lpthread -o Calc_XYZ.so
echo "Run GDB"
cd /opt/P01_SH/_Debug_Wrappers_in_C
gdb Call_Create_Threads_in_C-Calc_XYZ.exe
```

This script is run from _Debug_Wrappers_in_C, and a copy of the source file is in that directory.  When I run it locally on Ubuntu, GDB finds the source file and displays the line information as I debug:

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is Calc_XYZ.asm
Located in /opt/P01_SH/_Debug_Wrappers_in_C/Calc_XYZ.asm
Contains 1122 lines.
Source language is asm.
Producer is NASM 2.14.02.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

But on my new temporary droplet at Digital Ocean I get:

```
(gdb) info source
No current source file.
```

I tried "set substitute-path /opt/P01_SH/Calc_XYZ /opt/P01_SH/_Include_Utilities" but still no source lines show.

Why would I get the source file locally on Ubuntu 20.04, but not in the cloud (which is 22.04, but that shouldn't make a difference).  Locally NASM is version 2.14,02 and in the cloud it's 2.15.05.  I have run this same setup locally, and on other cloud servers, for several years without problems.  Why now?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: The script you gave rebuilds Calc_XYZ.so but then you run Calc_XYZ.exe.  Could you create a minimal reproducer, include source code and full steps to build, then we will be in a better place to help.

Comment: It calls "Call_Create_Threads_in_C-Calc_XYZ.exe," a minimal wrapper whose purpose is to call the shared object, not Calc_XYZ.exe.

Comment: "Why would I get the source file locally on Ubuntu 20.04, but not in the cloud" -- do the versions of `ld` differ between the two?

Comment: In the cloud ld is 2.38.  Locally it's 2.34.